# upgrade to Airflow 1.10.10

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I want to know if there are any major open issues around the core functionalities of Airflow such the Webserver, Scheduler and Worker on Airflow 1.10.10 before we perform the actual upgrade.

Ideally we expect the Scheduler hung issue should subside if not resolved in 1.10.10 ( This bug gave us head aches in 1.10.3). Pls confirm

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: What Airflow version are you currently using?